# How to ignore warnings of tika

Tags: apache-tika

Anybody help me!
I'm using a MacBook and install `Tika` via brew.
I have used `Tika` for a long without any problem, but after upgrading Tika warns like below;

```
$ tika
Dec 06, 2018 2:36:11 PM
org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
警告: J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed.
See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
for optional dependencies.

Dec 06, 2018 2:36:11 PM
org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
警告: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.
```

current config is below;

```
$ tika --dump-current-config
Dec 06, 2018 2:40:25 PM
org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
警告: J2KImageReader not loaded. JPEG2000 files will not be processed.
See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html#jai-image-io
for optional dependencies.

Dec 06, 2018 2:40:25 PM
org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
警告: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
  <!--for example: <mimeTypeRepository resource="/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml"/>-->
  <service-loader dynamic="true" loadErrorHandler="IGNORE"/>
  <encodingDetectors>
    <encodingDetector class="org.apache.tika.detect.DefaultEncodingDetector"/>
  </encodingDetectors>
  <translator class="org.apache.tika.language.translate.DefaultTranslator"/>
  <detectors>
    <detector class="org.apache.tika.detect.DefaultDetector"/>
  </detectors>
  <parsers>
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser"/>
  </parsers>
</properties>
```

`<service-loader dynamic="true" loadErrorHandler="IGNORE"/>` is written, what should I do further?

My usage of `tika` is to get diffs of microsoft office files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect the errors / warnings to /dev/null

eg.

```
tika <your arguments here> 2>/dev/null
```